# Using Overpass API in QGIS with osm file

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to implement `Overpass API` for one of my projects and not able to apply the `API`.

As there is some issue that queries are going to be implemented along the API and I am writing a **python** `script`.

I tried using the web version directly but there is no possibility that I can have any **analysis** there.

Comment: What do you mean by `Implementing the OverpassAPI`? What do you need in your Python script? Can you elaborate what you are trying to do in your Python script? Overpass is way to get OSM data. What are the issues you are talking about? You can launch your queries using the `QuickOSM plugin`, is-it what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that plugin I implemented it.

Comment: You can use QuickOSM in a Python script by using the QGIS Processing framework if needed.